# Switching from Server to Desktop

Tags: server, desktop-environments

I have Ubuntu server 12.10 and I would like to switch to desktop and would like to know how?

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

The server and desktop are basically the same thing but server does not have GUI stuff (xorg, desktop manager and ...) installed. On the same time server might have packages installed that would not be there if use Ubuntu on a desktop.

Before you start, it is always good to update packages list before you install something:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The easiest solution would be to use a program called Tasksel that you can install by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Run it by typing:

```
sudo tasksel
```

It gives you a simple gui to manage larger software bundles ("LAMP server", "Ubuntu desktop", "Lubuntu desktop") that have been installed in your system. Mark the stuff you need with asterisks by selecting them with up/down arrows and pressing space. After that press enter install what you have selected. To install regular Ubuntu desktop choose "Ubuntu desktop".

---

If the Tasksel does not work for some reason. You can install packages that come with the regular Desktop installation (Unity) with this:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you prefer Lubuntu flavour use the `lubuntu-desktop` package or if you prefer KDE use the `kubuntu-desktop` package or if you want Xfce use the `xubuntu-desktop` package instead of `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will tell you how it goes shortly.

Comment: I got the message :tasksel: aptitude failed (100)"
What should I do now?

Comment: If you want to switch immediately after installing, you may have to `sudo apt-get update` before the `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.