# Login to Ubuntu Server Desktop

Tags: system-installation

I'm new in Ubuntu aka Linux World. I already installed Ubuntu 14.10 Server on Dell PowerEdge t420. After done the installation it onlyu appears command line? My questions how to login to the desktop like windows or is it for ubuntu server only appear command line.

Thanks

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/322122/switching-from-server-to-desktop

Comment: BTW: re-installing is quicker than installing a desktop from commandline.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install a GUI. To do so, enter the following command -

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`

This will install the default Unity Desktop environment.

For installing XFCE -

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

or KDE -

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`

Similarly, you can install other desktop environments like LXDE, Mate, Gnome, Cinnamon, Openbox etc. etc.