# Installed 16.04 server on my laptop. How can convert it to a desktop

Tags: server

I installed 16.04 server on my Lenovo laptop with my only cd rom drive. Programs complain that there is no XServer. How can I get the screen working? I only have a command line.

Comment: Similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/322122/switching-from-server-to-desktop

Answer (score 2):

You can install the Xorg server by typing (as root): `apt-get install xorg`

This will only install Xorg though.  It will not install a complete DE.  If you want to install a complete DE, choose one of the available ubuntu variants without installing xorg manually:

`apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` or

`apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` or

`apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`  etc.

I would not install more than one of them though because there are several posts on help forums about systems that have started having problems after the user installed more than one DE.  This is not always the case though.  It's all up to you.