# Desktop automated netboot for 20.04

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, encryption, pxe

Previously, we've used the netboot method with a preseed file to automate provisioning developer workstations using PXE boot. But in 20.04 (focal fossa) netboot is no longer supported. There are recommendations on how to replace it with the server live install, however, I want to install a desktop. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to set up PXE boot for a desktop install of 20.04. How would I go about doing that?

Note: I need to have LUKS encryption with LVM on the root partition.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to install the desktop packages you want.  Packages like `ubuntu-desktop` will provide a lot.

See also:

- [Switching from Server to Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322122/switching-from-server-to-desktop)
- [Installed 16.04 server on my laptop. How can convert it to a desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773767/installed-16-04-server-on-my-laptop-how-can-convert-it-to-a-desktop)

This post has some tips specific to installing `ubuntu-desktop` from the new server autoinstall feature

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1292033/376778

This appears to provide an example of using `autoinstall` with LUKS and LVM

- [Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstallation LUKS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255724/ubuntu-20-04-autoinstallation-luks)