# Issues autoinstalling Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, ssh, kubuntu, pxe, cloud-init

I'm trying to make an automated installation of Kubuntu 20.04 with a PXE-Server. First using an ubuntu20.04-live-server image and the adding de kubuntu-desktop package. The thing is that I got lost at some point, because the autoinstaller doesn't do anything that appears on my user-data file.
Maybe someone can help me. This would be my PXE-Menu:

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 300
menu title PXE Menu
LABEL Install Kubuntu 20.04 with Autoinstall
 
    MENU LABEL  Install Kubuntu 20.04 with Autoinstall
    KERNEL initundkernel/vmlinuz
    INITRD initundkernel/initrd
    APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=150000i ip=dhcp url=http://myip/ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://myip/preseed/cloud-init/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null
```

The Menu works, it makes a correct installation of a plane ubuntu-server image, but that is all. It just pretends to read my user-data file:

```
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  apt:
    geoip: true
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  identity: {hostname: laptop17, password: $6$BCcme3szGenL3OjI$mj8X5xU97tQmqLkJyrTi3Aroi4Zx1D9a8kMAv08FmX15pK1FLcX5cBCLhYkwxCH1M9iRA2azSqmKMnKpkLAmw1,
    realname: localadmin, username: localadmin}
  keyboard: {layout: de, variant: nodeadkeys}
  locale: de
  network:
    ethernets: {}
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: 
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDQJj+FCD7xQKz0gDin7pLnqT15wBfeCbnKLWiAPuNBKTqjQT8TO7QaK6TskNVW2rg32ixcT4FGG8d047nMrNzVz61lIsVNiwCGZZQun6Vp6kqdUGP9upXS3ewhsmHNQNAXdZ+XUpUv+++1QU2RX4UEDJelrpIt i@mylaptop
    install-server: true
  storage:
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, serial: BIWIN_SSD_1832008401056, path: /dev/sda, wipe: superblock,
      preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true, type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1048576, flag: bios_grub, number: 1, preserve: false,
      grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 238979907584, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-2}
    - {volume: partition-2, keyfile: /tmp/luks-key-td2i_kos, preserve: false, type: dm_crypt,
      id: dm_crypt-0}
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices: [dm_crypt-0]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - {name: ubuntu-lv, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 119481040896B, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-0}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-0}
  version: 1
  
   packages:
   - build-essential
   - kubuntu-desktop

  late-commands:
   - sed -i 's/^#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   - service sshd restart
   - dhclient
```

I followed some documentations like the next one
https://louwrentius.com/understanding-the-ubuntu-2004-lts-server-autoinstaller.html#fnref:file but it doesn't work. I used /var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data file as example and then I just need to add few things like the kubuntu-desktop package and then openssh-server with my ssh-key and allowing login as root.

Any help would be welcome

Comment: Your `user-data` file **must** being with `#cloud-config`.  This is not optional.  Also, be careful installing a Desktop environment.  Some core components will be changed (e.g. NetworkManager replaces systemd-network).  This post has some suggested steps for Desktops https://askubuntu.com/a/1292033/376778