# Best path for reinstalling packages after bad downgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, kde

I was trying to compile a hello world c file.  I tried to apt-get install build_essentials but it said it couldn't because of g++ perhaps it was g++6.  I then told it to install that and it complained about something else.  Eventually it said it would have to downgrade something for me to install and I said go ahead.  I think it might have been libc.  I went through with it but then after I reboot the computer the kde login screen is unfamiliar and doesn't work.  It is blue with   I can still switch desktops to a console and log in.

I believe the ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. (or at least was before the command lol)

What is the recommended set of actions to get the system back up and running.  It is ok of gcc doesn't work.  I have other computers.  Is there a simple set of apt-get commands which will remove the stupid downgrade I put in and put things back to where they were?    I can confirm this and other things.

Here is what the login screen should look like:
[image]

And this is what the login screen does look like:
[image]

I found the apt-get log file.  It looks like the first thing which got uninstalled was kubuntu-desktop so installing that again may be the ticket.

```
Log started: 2021-12-25  09:00:35
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 247911 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing kubuntu-desktop (1.398) ...
Removing sddm-theme-breeze (4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing plasma-desktop (4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing xorg (1:7.7+19ubuntu14) ...
Removing gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing gcc-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing libgcc-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing libasan5:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing kinfocenter (4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing kubuntu-settings-desktop (1:20.04.9) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/newt/palette.ubuntu to provide /etc/newt/palette (newt-palette) in auto mode
Removing plasma-widgets-addons (4:5.18.4.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing plasma-workspace (4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing x11-xserver-utils (7.7+8) ...
Removing cpp (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing cpp-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing gcc-9-base:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Log ended: 2021-12-25  09:00:37

Log started: 2021-12-25  09:00:50
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-9-base:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 241133 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gcc-9-base_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-9-base:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up gcc-9-base:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Log ended: 2021-12-25  09:00:50

Log started: 2021-12-25  09:03:30
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 241138 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libsoup2.4-1:i386 (2.70.0-1) ...
Removing glib-networking:i386 (2.64.2-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing gstreamer1.0-x:i386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing va-driver-all:i386 (2.7.0-2) ...
Removing i965-va-driver:i386 (2.4.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing intel-media-va-driver:i386 (20.1.1+dfsg1-1) ...
Removing libaa1:i386 (1.4p5-46) ...
Removing wine32:i386 (5.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libwine:i386 (5.0-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing libfaudio0:i386 (20.04-2) ...
Removing libavcodec58:i386 (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libaom0:i386 (1.0.0.errata1-3build1) ...
Removing libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (2.0.10+dfsg1-3) ...
Removing libasound2-plugins:i386 (1.2.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpulse0:i386 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Removing libapparmor1:i386 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1) ...
Removing libsane:i386 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2) ...
Removing libcurl3-gnutls:i386 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Removing libldap-2.4-2:i386 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8) ...
Removing libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libopenal1:i386 (1:1.19.1-1) ...
Removing libsndio7.0:i386 (1.5.0-3) ...
Removing libasound2:i386 (1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.5) ...
Removing libasyncns0:i386 (0.8-6) ...
Removing libglu1-mesa:i386 (9.0.1-1build1) ...
Removing libgl1:i386 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libglx0:i386 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libglx-mesa0:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing libllvm11:i386 (1:11.0.0-2~ubuntu20.04.1) ...
Removing libcups2:i386 (2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libavahi-client3:i386 (0.7-4ubuntu7.1) ...
Removing libavahi-common3:i386 (0.7-4ubuntu7.1) ...
Removing libavc1394-0:i386 (0.5.4-5) ...
Removing libswresample3:i386 (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libavutil56:i386 (7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing librsvg2-common:i386 (2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing librsvg2-2:i386 (2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libbrotli1:i386 (1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing vdpau-driver-all:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing libsnmp35:i386 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3) ...
Removing libperl5.30:i386 (5.30.0-9ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libbz2-1.0:i386 (1.0.8-2) ...
Removing libssh-4:i386 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2) ...
Removing libmysqlclient21:i386 (8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing mesa-va-drivers:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
Removing libcaca0:i386 (0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2) ...
Removing libcairo-gobject2:i386 (1.16.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 (1.44.7-2ubuntu4) ...
Removing libshout3:i386 (2.4.3-1) ...
Removing libtheora0:i386 (1.1.1+dfsg.1-15ubuntu2) ...
Removing libcairo2:i386 (1.16.0-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 (1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (1.16.2-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (1.16.2-2) ...
Removing libcap2:i386 (1:2.32-1) ...
Removing libcapi20-3:i386 (1:3.27-3) ...
Removing libcdparanoia0:i386 (3.10.2+debian-13) ...
Removing libcodec2-0.9:i386 (0.9.2-2) ...
Removing libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing libkrb5-3:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing libwind0-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 (1.44.7-2ubuntu4) ...
Removing libpango-1.0-0:i386 (1.44.7-2ubuntu4) ...
Removing libthai0:i386 (0.1.28-3) ...
Removing libdatrie1:i386 (0.2.12-3) ...
Removing libsasl2-2:i386 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Removing libsasl2-modules-db:i386 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Removing libdb5.3:i386 (5.3.28+dfsg1-0.6ubuntu2) ...
Removing libdbus-1-3:i386 (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.105-3~20.04.2) ...
Removing libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.105-3~20.04.2) ...
Removing libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.105-3~20.04.2) ...
Removing libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.105-3~20.04.2) ...
Removing libva-x11-2:i386 (2.7.0-2) ...
Removing libva-drm2:i386 (2.7.0-2) ...
Removing libdrm2:i386 (2.4.105-3~20.04.2) ...
Removing libdv4:i386 (1.0.0-12) ...
Removing libelf1:i386 (0.176-1.1build1) ...
Removing libgphoto2-6:i386 (2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libexif12:i386 (0.6.21-6ubuntu0.4) ...
Removing libgd3:i386 (2.2.5-5.2ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libfontconfig1:i386 (2.13.1-2ubuntu3) ...
Removing libexpat1:i386 (2.2.9-1build1) ...
Removing librtmp1:i386 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1) ...
Removing libgnutls30:i386 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.6) ...
Removing libp11-kit0:i386 (0.23.20-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libwayland-cursor0:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Removing libwayland-client0:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Removing libsndfile1:i386 (1.0.28-7ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libflac8:i386 (1.3.3-1build1) ...
Removing libharfbuzz0b:i386 (2.6.4-1ubuntu4) ...
Removing libfreetype6:i386 (2.10.1-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libfribidi0:i386 (1.0.8-2) ...
Removing libosmesa6:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing libproxy1v5:i386 (0.4.15-10ubuntu1.2) ...
Removing libsystemd0:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Removing libxslt1.1:i386 (1.1.34-4) ...
Removing libgcrypt20:i386 (1.8.5-5ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libgdbm-compat4:i386 (1.18.1-5) ...
Removing libgdbm6:i386 (1.18.1-5) ...
Removing libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.40.0+dfsg-3ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libglapi-mesa:i386 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Removing libglvnd0:i386 (1.3.2-1~ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libhogweed5:i386 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libgmp10:i386 (2:6.2.0+dfsg-4) ...
Removing libsoxr0:i386 (0.1.3-2build1) ...
Removing libgomp1:i386 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing libgpg-error0:i386 (1.37-1) ...
Removing libgphoto2-port12:i386 (2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libgpm2:i386 (1.20.7-5) ...
Removing libgraphite2-3:i386 (1.3.13-11build1) ...
Removing libgsm1:i386 (1.0.18-2) ...
Removing libgudev-1.0-0:i386 (1:233-1) ...
Removing libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libxml2:i386 (2.9.10+dfsg-5ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libtag1v5:i386 (1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.3ubuntu2) ...
Removing libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 (1.11.1+dfsg.1-0.3ubuntu2) ...
Removing libicu66:i386 (66.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libpsl5:i386 (0.21.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libidn2-0:i386 (2.2.0-2) ...
Removing libiec61883-0:i386 (1.2.0-3) ...
Removing libieee1284-3:i386 (0.2.11-13build1) ...
Removing libigdgmm11:i386 (20.1.1+ds1-1) ...
Removing libjack-jackd2-0:i386 (1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing libtiff5:i386 (4.1.0+git191117-2ubuntu0.20.04.2) ...
Removing libjbig0:i386 (2.1-3.1build1) ...
Removing libv4l-0:i386 (1.18.0-2build1) ...
Removing libv4lconvert0:i386 (1.18.0-2build1) ...
Removing libjpeg8:i386 (8c-2ubuntu8) ...
Removing libjpeg-turbo8:i386 (2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1) ...
Removing libk5crypto3:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing libkeyutils1:i386 (1.6-6ubuntu1) ...
Removing libkrb5support0:i386 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing liblcms2-2:i386 (2.9-4) ...
Removing libodbc1:i386 (2.3.6-0.1build1) ...
Removing libltdl7:i386 (2.4.6-14) ...
Removing liblz4-1:i386 (1.9.2-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing liblzma5:i386 (5.2.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libmp3lame0:i386 (3.100-3) ...
Removing libmpg123-0:i386 (1.25.13-1) ...
Removing libncurses6:i386 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libncursesw6:i386 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libnettle7:i386 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libnghttp2-14:i386 (1.40.0-1build1) ...
Removing libx265-179:i386 (3.2.1-1build1) ...
Removing libnuma1:i386 (2.0.12-1) ...
Removing libvorbisenc2:i386 (1.3.6-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libvorbis0a:i386 (1.3.6-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libogg0:i386 (1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libopenjp2-7:i386 (2.3.1-1ubuntu4.20.04.1) ...
Removing libopus0:i386 (1.3.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing liborc-0.4-0:i386 (1:0.4.31-1) ...
Removing libpcap0.8:i386 (1.9.1-3) ...
Removing libpci3:i386 (1:3.6.4-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libpciaccess0:i386 (0.16-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libpixman-1-0:i386 (0.38.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libzvbi0:i386 (0.2.35-17) ...
Removing libpng16-16:i386 (1.6.37-2) ...
Removing libraw1394-11:i386 (2.1.2-1) ...
Removing libsamplerate0:i386 (0.1.9-2) ...
Removing libsasl2-modules:i386 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Removing libsensors5:i386 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libshine3:i386 (3.1.1-2) ...
Removing libslang2:i386 (2.3.2-4) ...
Removing libsnappy1v5:i386 (1.1.8-1build1) ...
Removing libspeex1:i386 (1.2~rc1.2-1.1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libsqlite3-0:i386 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2) ...
Removing libstb0:i386 (0.0~git20190817.1.052dce1-1) ...
Removing libtasn1-6:i386 (4.16.0-2) ...
Removing libtwolame0:i386 (0.4.0-2) ...
Removing libusb-1.0-0:i386 (2:1.0.23-2build1) ...
Removing libudev1:i386 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Removing libunistring2:i386 (0.9.10-2) ...
Removing libuuid1:i386 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1) ...
Removing libva2:i386 (2.7.0-2) ...
Removing libvdpau1:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libvisual-0.4-0:i386 (0.4.0-17) ...
Removing libvkd3d1:i386 (1.1-4) ...
Removing libvpx6:i386 (1.8.2-1build1) ...
Removing libvulkan1:i386 (1.2.131.2-1) ...
Removing libwavpack1:i386 (5.2.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libwayland-egl1:i386 (1.18.0-1) ...
Removing libwebpmux3:i386 (0.6.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libwebp6:i386 (0.6.1-2ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Removing libwrap0:i386 (7.6.q-30) ...
Removing libxxf86vm1:i386 (1:1.1.4-1build1) ...
Removing libxv1:i386 (2:1.0.11-1) ...
Removing libx264-155:i386 (2:0.155.2917+git0a84d98-2) ...
Removing libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-dri2-0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-glx0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-present0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-randr0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-render0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-shm0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-sync1:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcb-xfixes0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxcomposite1:i386 (1:0.4.5-1) ...
Removing libxcursor1:i386 (1:1.2.0-2) ...
Removing libxdamage1:i386 (1:1.1.5-2) ...
Removing libxss1:i386 (1:1.2.3-1) ...
Removing libxfixes3:i386 (1:5.0.3-2) ...
Removing libxi6:i386 (2:1.7.10-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libxinerama1:i386 (2:1.1.4-2) ...
Removing libxkbcommon0:i386 (0.10.0-1) ...
Removing libxpm4:i386 (1:3.5.12-1) ...
Removing libxrandr2:i386 (2:1.5.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libxrender1:i386 (1:0.9.10-1) ...
Removing libxshmfence1:i386 (1.3-1) ...
Removing libxvidcore4:i386 (2:1.3.7-1) ...
Removing libzstd1:i386 (1.4.4+dfsg-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (2.2.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libllvm12:i386 (1:12.0.0-3ubuntu1~20.04.4) ...
Removing libatomic1:i386 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.64.6-1~ubuntu20.04.4) ...
Removing libmount1:i386 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1) ...
Removing libblkid1:i386 (2.34-0.1ubuntu9.1) ...
Removing libedit2:i386 (3.1-20191231-1) ...
Removing libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9) ...
Removing libcom-err2:i386 (1.45.5-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libroken18-heimdal:i386 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libffi7:i386 (3.3-4) ...
Removing libstdc++6:i386 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Removing libselinux1:i386 (3.0-1build2) ...
Removing libpcre2-8-0:i386 (10.34-7) ...
Removing libpcre3:i386 (2:8.39-12build1) ...
Removing libtinfo6:i386 (6.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing zlib1g:i386 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.2) ...
Removing libx11-6:i386 (2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2) ...
Removing libxcb1:i386 (1.14-2) ...
Removing libxdmcp6:i386 (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libbsd0:i386 (0.10.0-1) ...
Removing libxau6:i386 (1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libc6:i386 (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
Removing libcrypt1:i386 (1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) ...
Removing libgcc-s1:i386 (10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) ...
[1mdpkg:[0m [1;33mwarning:[0m while removing libgcc-s1:i386, directory '/lib/i386-linux-gnu' not empty so not removed
[1mdpkg:[0m [1;33mwarning:[0m downgrading libc6:amd64 from 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 to 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 237091 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) over (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 237091 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libpulse-mainloop-glib0_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libpulsedsp_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-pulseaudio-utils_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-utils (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-pulseaudio_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libpulse0_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpulse0:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.12) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) over (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc-dev-bin.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libc-dev-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-libc-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-linux-libc-dev_5.4.0-91.102_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-91.102) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcrypt-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libcrypt-dev_1%3a4.4.10-10ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcrypt-dev:amd64 (1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libc6-dev_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp-9.
Preparing to unpack .../11-cpp-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package cpp.
Preparing to unpack .../12-cpp_4%3a9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasan5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libasan5_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan5:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-9-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libgcc-9-dev_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-9.
Preparing to unpack .../15-gcc-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc.
Preparing to unpack .../16-gcc_4%3a9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-9-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libstdc++-9-dev_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-9.
Preparing to unpack .../18-g++-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../19-g++_4%3a9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package make.
Preparing to unpack .../20-make_4.2.1-1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking make (4.2.1-1.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdpkg-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libdpkg-perl_1.19.7ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libdpkg-perl (1.19.7ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../22-dpkg-dev_1.19.7ubuntu3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.19.7ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../23-build-essential_12.8ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.8ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libfakeroot_1.24-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.24-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../25-fakeroot_1.24-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.24-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../26-libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../27-libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-6) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../28-libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../29-libegl-mesa0_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../30-libgbm1_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgbm1:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../31-libosmesa6_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../32-libgl1-mesa-dri_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../33-libglx-mesa0_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../34-libglapi-mesa_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfile-fcntllock-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../35-libfile-fcntllock-perl_0.22-3build4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package manpages-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../36-manpages-dev_5.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking manpages-dev (5.05-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../37-mesa-va-drivers_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../38-mesa-vdpau-drivers_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../39-mesa-vulkan-drivers_21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) over (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.4) ...
Setting up mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up manpages-dev (5.05-1) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libpulse0:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up libfile-fcntllock-perl (0.22-3build4) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-2) ...
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-91.102) ...
Setting up libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.24-1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.24-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Setting up libasan5:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up make (4.2.1-1.2) ...
Setting up libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-utils (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libdpkg-perl (1.19.7ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libcrypt-dev:amd64 (1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) ...
Setting up cpp-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-6) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up pulseaudio (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.19.7ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libgcc-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up libegl-mesa0:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up cpp (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Setting up gcc-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:amd64 (21.0.3-0ubuntu0.3~20.04.5) ...
Setting up libstdc++-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up g++-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Setting up g++ (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.3) ...
Log ended: 2021-12-25  09:03:56
```

Comment: Its a little confusing on what apt is trying to say to you here without any error messages provided, do you mind sharing the exact error messages you got?

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/322162/26246 it may get fixed. If not please share more details, at least how your current login screen (camera photo may help) understand the situation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @user.dz.  I'll give that a shot.  If it doesn't help I'll try taking a screenshot of the computer.  ElegantShock2258 I don't have the exact error messages any more unless I can find them in a log somewhere.  I didn't know I toasted the computer until I tried to reboot.  You are right as I should have copied them down.

Comment: @user.dz That did it.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!  Post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.  I'll be more careful next time I try to install gcc.  btw I participated in AdventOfCode the first time this year and it was a blast.  :-)

Comment: To Close Reviewer, the question has been updated with more details from the time it was flagged for 1st flagged. Logs included which gave enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

Could fix the desktop. [`kubuntu-desktop`](https://askubuntu.com/a/322162/26246) is a meta package for KDE.

It is from previous experience. Usually, two issues may cause such results with login screen.

- Default Display Manager DM removed or replaced with newly installed, due a conflict between packages ([Unmet dependency](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/26246) with some base libraries) or new Desktop Environment DE was installed.
- Or an issue with DM itself or its settings.

BTW, it was first case, I would recommend trying `aptitude` when having unmet dependencies and flip over provided solutions, not all get to downgrade or remove many packages.